# import error with pyg-lib and torch-sparse

Tags: import, pytorch, cpu, pytorch-geometric

I have been facing an issue with importing torch_geometric, every-time I run, `from torch_geometric.nn import MessagePassing` I get a stack trace as follows -

> /Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_geometric/typing.py:18: UserWarning: An issue occurred while importing 'pyg-lib'. Disabling its usage. Stacktrace: dlopen(/Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libpyg.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib
> Referenced from: <17EC4CAB-AF50-3E98-8969-F2498B67D840> /Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libpyg.so
> Reason: tried: '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
> warnings.warn(f"An issue occurred while importing 'pyg-lib'. "
> /Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_geometric/typing.py:42: UserWarning: An issue occurred while importing 'torch-sparse'. Disabling its usage. Stacktrace: dlopen(/Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libpyg.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib
> Referenced from: <17EC4CAB-AF50-3E98-8969-F2498B67D840> /Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libpyg.so
> Reason: tried: '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpython3.10.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
> warnings.warn(f"An issue occurred while importing 'torch-sparse'. "

I have tried multiple installations using anaconda and pip both, I always run into this issue. I checked other posts and some claim this is a multiple-python-versions issue, but when I run `conda list python -n PyGtut` I get the following output -

> packages in environment at /Users/karan_bania/anaconda3/envs/PyGtut:
> Name                      Version            Build Channel 
> ipython                   8.12.0             py310hecd8cb5_0
> ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
> python                    3.10.8               h218abb5_1
> python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
> python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310hecd8cb5_0
> python-json-logger        2.0.7           py310hecd8cb5_0
> python-lsp-black          1.2.1           py310hecd8cb5_0
> python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
> python-lsp-server         1.7.2           py310hecd8cb5_0
> python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
> python.app                3               py310hca72f7f_0

Which clearly shows I have just one version of Python. Also earlier I had 3.11.1 which I downgraded to 3.10.8 because the error showed the message. I think there is some issue with **where** the packages get installed but I am not able to figure out how to solve it.

I am using a macOS with torch==2.0.0.

Comment: I was able to find a solution but it seems rather unusual why this error would occur in the first place, if someone is able to figure that out please do answer the question. My answer - 
What I did was simply search for python3.10dylib with finder for the corresponding environment, and copy-pasted it to `/usr/local/lib/` and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have a full answer for you yet, but my current analysis tells me there is something wrong with the installer of PyTorch Geometric, as I had the same issue with a different dependency (Torch_Spline_Conv). Importing torch and the dependency gave me the same error, solved it by installing directly from Binarys, see [Rusty's Github page](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_spline_conv). Maybe this helps others too.